# Update drawable with data binding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have an `ImageView` that i change the alpha on depending on if a String is present.

**XML**

```
<data>
    <import type="android.text.TextUtils"/>
    <variable name="model" type="myPackage.Model"/>
</data>

<TextView
    android:text="@={model.stringAttribute}"/>

<ImageView
    android:alpha='@{model.stringAttribute.eqals("") ? 0.5f : 1.0f }'
    android:src="@drawable/thing"/>
```

And in my `activity`:

```
binding.setModel(model);
```

This works except that the alpha on the `ImageView` only updates when the activity is restarted. I've tried adding the equal sign after the @ but that will not compile.

**Model**

```
public class Model extends BaseObservable {
    private String stringAttribute;
    public void setStringAttribute(String s) {
        stringAttribute = s
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.stringAttribute)
    }
    @Bindable
    public String getStringAttribute() {
        return stringAttribute;
    }
}
```

And to clarify, `TextView` updates when the model is changed. It's just the alpha on the `ImageView` that will not update until the activity is restarted.

Comment: Does your model use `ObservableField` for `stringAttribute` or is it `Observable`? If neither, then that's your problem.

Comment: It is observable (annotated with `@Bindable`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<data>
    <import type="android.text.TextUtils"/>
    <variable name="model" type="yourPackage.MainViewModel"/>
</data>

...

<ImageView
    android:alpha='@{TextUtils.isEmpty(model.stringAttribute) ? 0.5 : 1.0 }'
    android:src="@drawable/thing"/>
```

Make sure you are also setting `model` from activity like

```
binding.setModel(model);
```

Comment: I have updated my question, the `TextView` updates fine when the model is changed. It's just the alpha setting on the drawable that's not working.

Comment: That won't compile. The code is OK on that part. The expression evaluates and the alpha changes, it just will not update the GUI without the activity being restarted.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` is for two-way binding, which makes no sense for an imageView (user can't change the image). You don't show the code for `myPackage.Model`. Make sure that the model extends BaseObservable (there are other ways to do this as well) and that the setter for `stringAttribute` is calling `notifyChange()` or `notifyPropertyChanged()`, e.g.:

```
public void setStringAttribute(String val) {
    . . .
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.stringAttribute);
}
```

Comment: `notifyPropertyChanged()` is in the setter and class extends `BaseObservable`. The string-property is annotated with `@Bindable`

Comment: Also make sure notifyPropertyChanged is the last thing called in the setter. And you might also try setting and testing against null, just in case.